# JSON Response shows null when trying to use data models

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I am fetching content from a webservice which provides json output.I followed [this](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/how-to-fetch-and-parse-json-by-using-data-models/) tutorial for refrence.The problem is now I am getting a null response.

This is what I have done so far.
This is the blog model

```
  #import "JSONModel.h"
 @protocol BlogModel <NSObject>
 @end


 @interface BlogModel : JSONModel
 @property int *ID_article;
 @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *titre;
 @end
```

This is Blog Feed

```
 #import "JSONModel.h"
 #import "BlogModel.h"


@interface BlogFeed : JSONModel
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray <BlogModel> *blogModel;
@end
```

And this is the View Controller.

```
 @implementation ViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];

blogFeed = [[BlogFeed alloc]initFromURLWithString:@"http://web_services/My_blog.php" completion:^(JSONModel *model , JSONModelError *err)
{

     NSLog(@"blog Content :- %@ " , blogFeed.blogModel); // shows null
     [self.blogTableView reloadData];

}];
```

Sample Json response....

```
    [
{
    "0": "1",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "Barndoor 51 : the rescue mission",
    "3": "Barndoor are pretty rare busses, so you can be very happy when you find one... (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). But if you find a pre-52 one, you are a even more lucky guy (...lire la suite)</span>",
    "4": "                    Barndoor are pretty rare busses, so you can be very happy when you find one... (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). But if you find a pre-52 one, you are a even more lucky guy ! So if more than that it does not have a rear windows, yeah, that's you day. \r\n (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). A bientot pour un la suite !!",
    "5": "23_841676772.jpg",
    "6": "2013-06-06 08:11:15",
    "7": "",
    "8": "1",
    "9": "5",
    "ID": "1",
    "ID_auteur": "1",
    "titre": "Barndoor 51 : the rescue mission",
    "apercu": "Barndoor are pretty rare busses, so you can be very happy when you find one... (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). But if you find a pre-52 one, you are a even more lucky guy (...lire la suite)</span>",
    "article": "                    Barndoor are pretty rare busses, so you can be very happy when you find one... (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). But if you find a pre-52 one, you are a even more lucky guy ! So if more than that it does not have a rear windows, yeah, that's you day. \r\n (I mean, a true find, where you have to pick up the bus in a barn or in the wild... not ni the garage of the previous owner after finding it in the classifieds !). A bientot pour un la suite !!",
    "photo": "23_841676772.jpg",
    "date": "2013-06-06 08:11:15",
    "tags": "",
    "ID_article": "1",
    "commentcount": "5"
},
// similar content
]
```

Comment: +1 Can you please post your response what it would be ? Simply open that link in browser and check response.

Comment: your json seems to be incorrect check it here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: If I do it by normal way using NSJSONSerialization and collecting the results in a dictionary , I can easily get hold of the objects....However when I try this approach , I am getting no success.

Comment: Your json is not in proper format [Check here](http://json.parser.online.fr/) or [Here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org).

Comment: Okay JSON response is valid now....please check update..